# How to understand the result of output with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a judgment code of even/odd numbers with C++ templates.

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N, int Mod2=N%2>
struct Print {
  Print() {
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int N>
struct Print<N, 0> {
  Print() {
    std::cout << "Even!" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int N>
struct Print<N, 1> {
  Print() {
    std::cout << "Odd!" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <int N>
struct EvenOdd {
  EvenOdd() {
    EvenOdd<N+1>();
    Print<N>();
  }
};

template <>
struct EvenOdd<10> {
  EvenOdd() {
    std::cout << "Hey!" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  EvenOdd<0>();
  return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
$ ./a.out
Hey!
Odd!
Even!
Odd!
Even!
Odd!
Even!
Odd!
Even!
Odd!
Even!
```

I predicted that

```
EvenOdd<10>::EvenOdd() //=> "Hey!"
```

is called lastly. But, it's mistake.

Why does "Hey!" output firstly?

Answer (score 7):

This behavior has nothing to do with templates specifically. It is basic recursion. You recursively instantiate `EvenOdd` *before* printing. And so the first instance to print anything is the innermost, which is `EvenOdd<10>`.

Here's what happens: the first thing `EvenOdd<0>` does is to instantiate `EvenOdd<1>`. Only when that completes, does it call `Print<0>`. And that doesn't complete until `EvenOdd<1>` has finished instantiating `EvenOdd<2>` and printed, and so on:

```
EvenOdd<0>
 EvenOdd<1>
  EvenOdd<2>
   EvenOdd<3>
    EvenOdd<4>
     EvenOdd<5>
      EvenOdd<6>
       EvenOdd<7>
        EvenOdd<8>
         EvenOdd<9>
          EvenOdd<10>
          std::cout << "Hey!" << std::endl;
         Print<9>
        Print<8>
       Print<7>
      Print<6>
     Print<5>
    Print<4>
   Print<3>
  Print<2>
 Print<1>
Print<0>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your template `EvenOdd` is explicitly specialized for the parameter `10` only, all other specializations' constructors instantiate an anonymous `EvenOdd` for the template parameter `N+1` as the first action in their constructor.

This means that the `EvenOdd` constructor will recursively generate anonymous `EvenOdd` temporary objects up to the template parameter 10 before any `EvenOdd` object constructs a `Print` Object.

Constructing the 11th `EvenOdd` object results in outputting "Hey!", then the first `Print` object is constructed.